# iOS: Is there a safe way to include an API key in the code?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon has an AWS SDK for iOS, along with [several sample apps](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples). In their samples, they put the API credentials in a `Constants.h` file:

```
// Constants used to represent your AWS Credentials.
#define ACCESS_KEY_ID          @"CHANGE ME"
#define SECRET_KEY             @"CHANGE ME"
```

My concern is that these can be extracted by a determined hacker. Is there any way to securely include API keys in an app?

The one option I've seen is to include a server of my own as a go-between: the app talks to my server, my server talks to S3. I can see the value in doing this, but one is still presented with the problem: do I allow the app to make API calls on my server without any kind of authentication? Including my own API key in the app has the same problem as including AWS API keys.

Comment: If they are stored in the app (especially in clear text), then they can be retrieved.  Can your app retrieve the key on first run (using https) and then store it using a `KeychainItemWrapper`.  If so, you should also make sure you also set the appropriate level of app security for accessing the keychain.

Comment: That is starting to sound like a good idea. I could even work out something to force it to expire after a week, in case I need to change to a different set of credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of credential management options to help you avoid embedding credentials in your app. The first is Web Identity Federation, which allows users to log in to your app with Facebook, Google, or Login With Amazon. Another option is to use a Token Vending Machine, which is a server component that distributes temporary credentials to your app.

There is a high-level overview with pointers to the relevant documentation and code samples on the AWS Mobile Development Blog: http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3UKF4SV4V0LV3/Announcing-Web-Identity-Federation

Comment: For this use case, the Token Vending Machine sounds like the best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to create temporary write credentials using AWS STS tokens instead of passing keys all the way to the client. You can also create OAIs for CloudFront endpoints so no users directly access S3.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably you colud store them in an encoded form and encode them as needed.

Comment: You would be either relying on obfuscation which is reversible or encryption. If you encrypted the keys, you would still have to store the key for decryption which is then a recursive problem.  How would you store the encryption key?

Comment: @StephenJohnson Obfuscating the key is still a big improvement over using plain text.

Comment: @rmaddy - nice approach to obfuscation: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/obfuscation-encryption-of-string-nsstring.html

Answer (score -1):

Did you try a `KeychainItemWrapper` ?

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = 
 [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestAppLoginData" accessGroup:nil];
```

to Set

```
[keychain setObject:@"some text" forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[keychain setObject:@"some pass" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

to Get

```
NSString *text = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
NSString *pass = [keychain objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

[Keychain Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html)

Before import `Security.framwork`

I didn't check this code, if something doesn't work, let me know

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. How does this hide the key? This still requires the key to be in the code.

Comment: @rmaddy `Is there any way to securely include API keys in an app?`. Probably I misunderstood

Comment: Read the code in the question. He has a key in his code. He is asking how to hide that key from the code so a hacker can't find it. Using the keychain doesn't hide the key from the app's code.

Comment: This answer is not relevant to the question that was asked.